# Any reason this is outputting a higher amount than I'd like it to?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, logic

I'm not sure if this is just looping more than it should or if my numbers are wrong, but it should be:

IF dept is 10 and the salary is greater than 2000 give a 6% raise otherwise give a 7% raise. IF dept is 20 and the salary is greater than 2500 give a 5% raise otherwise give a 5.5% raise. IF dept is 30 and the salary is greater than 1000 give a 7% raise otherwise give a 6.5% raise.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE
    v_deptno        empbackup.deptno%TYPE;
    v_sal           empbackup.sal%TYPE;
    CURSOR raise IS
        SELECT deptno, sal
        FROM empbackup
        FOR UPDATE OF sal;

BEGIN
    OPEN raise;
    FETCH raise INTO v_deptno, v_sal;

    WHILE raise%FOUND LOOP
        IF v_deptno = 10 AND v_sal > 2000 THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.06;
        ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.07;
        END IF;

        IF v_deptno = 20 AND v_sal > 2500 THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.05;
        ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.055;
        END IF;

        IF v_deptno = 30 AND v_sal > 1000 THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.07;
        ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.065;
        END IF;

        UPDATE empbackup
        SET sal = v_sal
        WHERE CURRENT OF raise;

        FETCH raise INTO v_deptno, v_sal;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE raise;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please tag correctly. Is this mySQL or Oracle? Can't be both

Comment: Could you please provide test data for which the code doesn't return expected values?

Comment: Time to investigate the PL/SQL debugger. btw you can simplify this code with a [Cursor FOR loop](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `IF`'s. The department check and salary check should not be in a single `IF`. Otherwise a row with department 20 will go to `ELSE` parts of first and third `IF`'s and the `IF` part of second `IF`. The following code will work.

```
DECLARE
   v_deptno   empbackup.deptno%TYPE;
   v_sal      empbackup.sal%TYPE;

   CURSOR raise
   IS
          SELECT deptno, sal
            FROM empbackup
      FOR UPDATE OF sal;
BEGIN
   OPEN raise;

   FETCH raise
   INTO v_deptno, v_sal;

   WHILE raise%FOUND
   LOOP
      IF v_deptno = 10
      THEN
         IF v_sal > 2000
         THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.06;
         ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.07;
         END IF;
      END IF;

      IF v_deptno = 20
      THEN
         IF v_sal > 2500
         THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.05;
         ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.055;
         END IF;
      END IF;

      IF v_deptno = 30
      THEN
         IF v_sal > 1000
         THEN
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.07;
         ELSE
            v_sal := v_sal * 1.065;
         END IF;
      END IF;

      UPDATE empbackup
         SET sal = v_sal
       WHERE CURRENT OF raise;

      FETCH raise
      INTO v_deptno, v_sal;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE raise;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nitish.  I'm a bit newer to this site, how do I "accept" your answer so this can close?

Comment: @JBen There will be a tick mark on the left of the answer. You just need to click that. It'll become green.